# Magento2: Add a New Customer Address

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, soap, address

I'm trying to add a new customer address using Magento 2 REST API in C#. I'm using POST /V1/customers/:id. I keep getting the below error. Where do I find the regionId? Is there another API I can use to get it because I can't easily query the Magento database everytime.

```
{  
   "message":"%fieldName is a required field.",
   "parameters":{  
      "fieldName":"regionId"
   }
}
```

Here is the JSON request:

```
{
"customer":{
    "email":"customer@example.com",
    "firstname":"John",
    "lastname":"Doe",
    "websiteId":"1",
    "addresses":[
        {
            "customer_id":"1",
            "firstname":"John",
            "lastname":"Doe",
            "company":"ABC Manufacturing",
            "telephone":"555-555-5555",
            "city":"Boston",
            "region":"Massachusetts",
            "postcode":"02115",
            "country_id":"US",
            "street":[
                "123 Main Street",
                "PO Box 321"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will get all the customer address related attributes by calling **below url :**

> http://yourwebsite.com/index.php/rest//V1/attributeMetadata/customerAddress/
>
> Method Name : GET
>
> Same way for Authorization Bearer youraccesstoken

You will get the all the address related attributes name and its values **like state , country etc.**

Their you will find **RegionId** for your **region** **( Example : Massachusetts = 32) Where 32 is region Id.**

At last pass below parameters to **add customer address with same url**.

```
{
"customer":{
    "email":"cusaaastomesr@example.com",
    "firstname":"John",
    "lastname":"Doe",
    "websiteId":"1",
    "addresses":[
        {
            "customer_id":"3",
            "region_id": 32, // RegionId must needs to pass
            "country_id":"US",
            "street":[
                "123 Main Street",
                "PO Box 321"
            ],
            "firstname":"John",
            "lastname":"Doe",
            "company":"ABC Manufacturing",
            "telephone":"555-555-5555",
            "city":"Boston",
            "postcode":"02115"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

It will update address of customer and **your error will resolved**.

Refer this link for all api details - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/list.html
or
https://r-martins.github.io/m1docs/guides/v2.4/rest/list.html

Comment: This is not working for me. Getting blank list in response

Comment: @GauravAgrawal - check your parameters all are there or not ? also check your method and access token as well , if still  getting blank then post your issue as an new question and comment link here then i  will check it and let you know for the same

Comment: @ManthanDave I tried this code working. one up vote. it is creating new address in customer but all other addresses deleted. can you guide me to add new address with rest api

Comment: @TirthPatel You need to add an array of addresses, so when you get customers from API you get addresses but also add those addresses as well as new addresses in this request body.