# How to add address to customer after register using REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I have used This API as in the first image to create customer[image]
now I want to add the address for this customer please tell me how to do so?
Thanks,

Comment: there is no endpoint for creating customer addresses

Comment: @PhilippSander Then how to do so? can you give some idea

Comment: provide an endpoint

Comment: It might be help https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172659/magento2-add-a-new-customer-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add address by using bellow api -

**Endpoint**:       customers/me

**Method**:         PUT/GET

**Token**:          Customer-Token

Get method -> fetch information of customer.

Put method -> add or update address of customer.

**Request Body(add edit only personal information or create user):**

```
{
"customer":{
"firstname":"firstname",
"lastname":"lastname",
"email":"rakeshchand@gmail.com",
"store_id": 1,
"website_id":1
}
}
```

**Add address of existing customer -**
**Method:** Put

**Request Body:**

```
{
"customer":{
"firstname":"firstname",
"lastname":"lastname",
"email":"rakeshchand1990@gmail.com",
"store_id": 1,
"website_id":1,
"addresses":[
{
"country_id":"IN",
"firstname":"Rakesh",
"lastname":"Chand",
"city":"Muktsar",
"telephone":"1234561230",
"postcode":"210302",
"Default_shipping":1,                          // 1 for true & 0 for false
"default_billing":1,
"Street":["ganj"],
"region":{
"region_code":"PB",
"region":"Punjab",
"Region_id":1678
}]
}
]
}
}
```

**add one more address -**

Method: Put

Request Body:

```
    {
        "customer":{
        "firstname":"firstname",
        "lastname":"lastname",
        "email":"rakeshchand1990@gmail.com",
        "store_id": 1,
        "website_id":1,
        "addresses":[
        {
        "id": 181,    // use previous address id 
        "country_id":"IN",
        "firstname":"Rakesh",
        "lastname":"Chand",
        "city":"Muktsar",
        "telephone":"1234561230",
        "postcode":"210302",
        "Default_shipping":1,                          // 1 for true & 0 for false
        "default_billing":1,
        "Street":["ganj"],
        "region":{
        "region_code":"PB",
        "region":"Punjab",
        "Region_id":1678
        }, 
{  // this is one more address 
        "country_id":"IN",
        "firstname":"Rakesh1",
        "lastname":"Chand1",
        "city":"Muktsar",
        "telephone":"1234561230",
        "postcode":"210303",
        "Default_shipping":1,                          // 1 for true & 0 for false
        "default_billing":1,
        "Street":["ganj"],
        "region":{
        "region_code":"PB",
        "region":"Punjab",
        "Region_id":1678
        }
]
        }
        ]
        }
        }
```

Please note bellow points -

1-> if you want small changes on any one address then you need create request body of all address with changes address.

2-> if you remove any address from request body that means you want delete this address.

3-> don't change previous address id. if you do than magento delete this address and create new with new address id.

This information will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response but if i want to change the address of existing customer? because  i already created customer

Comment: also, a person can have multiple addresses how can we achieve same

Comment: Yes you can do both think.

Comment: sir if I send it again then old address gets deleted and new stored how can we achieve multiple addresses can you please tell

Comment: please check updated answer.

Comment: please tell me if you facing any issue.

Comment: adding multiple address is still an issue because i can't see any difference in your both answers

Comment: Please check this comment // this is one more address  --> this is way for adding more address as array of address

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90297/discussion-between-adarsh-shukla-and-rakesh-chand).